# Definite articles for 1st person singular

Tags: definite-article

I know this is a bit contrived, but with literature about clones and time travel and parallel universes, this is bound to come up.

> I traveled to 1995, and the I that I saw was not the I I remember being.

Feel free to be imaginive, and please let me know which definite articles sound right with "der ich".

Comment: Correct punctuation would help a lot, to make that English sentence more comprehensible.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I assume you want to say that it would make the text easier to read for *you* if English used German punctuation.

Comment: @Carsten No, correct English punctuation would be completely sufficient.

Comment: @CarstenS Not my A-level force, but I believe it should be _"I traveled to 1995, and the I that I saw, was not the I I remember being."_

Comment: Common grammar does not cover time travel well, but I believe it should say *...was not the I I remember having been*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct definite article for 1st person singular as noun is *das*:

> Ich reiste *(zurück)* nach 1995 und **das** Ich, das ich sah, war nicht **das** Ich, das ich mich erinnerte zu sein.

According to [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=ich) (emphasis mine):

> > NOUN     **das** Ich | die Ichs/Ich

Thus the English term *the I* clearly translates to the *das Ich* in German.

Comment: It is *erinnern an*, so *an das ich mich erinnerte zu sein.* or *an das zu sein ich mich erinnerte.*

Comment: @rexkogitans Danke!

Comment: "Das Ich" referes to the psychologigal "Ich" in the model of Sigmund Freud, who also coined the concept. Are you sure this "Ich" is the same as the one in teh example?

Comment: @Beta Pretty sure. And there's not much difference though for the noun.

Comment: @Beta. Freud did not coin "das ich". It was used by Fichte in the 18th century, and by others since.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ's translation is correct.

Comment: Der letzte Nebensatz ist kaputt: Die Präposition „an“ vor dem Relativpronomen ergibt eine (infinite) Verbgruppe mit folgenden möglichen Positionen für „an“: „sich [an] erinnern [an] zu sein“. Keine davon erscheint mir korrekt und sinnvoll. Wie wäre es ohne „an“? „[…] das Ich, das ich mich erinnerte zu sein.“ Ansonsten +1.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Ich habe es wieder zurückgeeändert. Der erste Kommentar hatte mich diesbezüglich etwas verwirrt.

Comment: @DavidFoerster May be a dialectical difference. To me, it sounds incomplete without *an*. I am Austrian.

Comment: @rexkogitans Well, I am bavarian. But for me the original variant also sounds better, thus I changed it back again.

Comment: @rexkogitans: Der Ausdruck, soweit ich ihn kenne, ist "sich an etwas erinnern" oder "sich erinnern zu [Infinitiv]".

Answer (score 3):

Very probably, you wouldn't use "Ich" in that subclause at all, but rather refer to yourself in third person:

> Ich reiste zurück nach 1995 und erkannte, dass ich, der ich mich dort antraf, nicht der war, der ich glaubte, gewesen zu sein.

Comment: For the sake of clarity you might want to add that in your translation _der_ is not the definite article of _ich_.

Comment: Could you use "die" in case you were female?

Comment: @Beta Yes, you can.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of simplification I wouldn't try to translate it verbatim too.

> *I traveled to 1995 and the I that I saw was not the I I remember being.*
>
> - Ich reiste ins Jahr 1995, fand mich jedoch nicht so, wie ich mich aus
>     dieser Zeit in Erinnerung habe.
> - Ich reiste ins Jahr 1995, erkannte mich aber nicht als den, den ich von
>     damals in Erinnerung habe.

Comment: For sake of literal connotation trust, I'd avoid such wide interpretation, Also I don't really see a _"sine qua non"_ with that construct.